# Mage registry key "_singleton/admin/session" already exists

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, admin-panel

When clicking on Magento Connect Manager from admin, facing this error: Mage registry key "_singleton/admin/session" already exists

Comment: Try using full name of class instead of a modelized one. Helped in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a solution, but I can explain why/when this is happening.

**TL;DR:** In your case the model `admin/session` is not instantiated or does not exist and `Mage::getModel('admin/session')` returns false

**Full explanation**

There is a bug (or better yet an inconsistency) in the `Mage::getSingleton` method.
It has been there for ages.

The method looks like this:

```
public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

Now let's take a look at the `Mage::register` method

```
public static function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)
{
    if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
        if ($graceful) {
            return;
        }
        self::throwException('Mage registry key "'.$key.'" already exists');
    }
    self::$_registry[$key] = $value;
}
```

Notice the `throwException`. It is exactly what you see as error message. If there is already a value in the registry for a certain key, you get an error.
In your case you get this error because there is already a value for key `_singleton/admin/session`. This happens in one case.
Going back to the `getSingleton` method, this is the bug/inconsistency:

```
 if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
```

This condition will return `true` when the value you registered for a specific key is `null, false, 0`.
This happens when `getModel` returns `false`. (when a model class is not found).

You should check if you have extensions rewriting the admin session class, or you can debug starting from the methods above to see why you are getting this error.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue with overriding `catalogSearch` class. I'm overriding in following way in global section config.xml of custommodule: `<models>
          <catalogsearch>
              <rewrite>
                  <layer>MY_Custommodule_Model_CatalogSearch_Layer</layer>
              </rewrite>
          </catalogsearch>
       </models>`

Comment: [see here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/59412/18509) for a slightly clearer explanation. It seems the overriding classes don't necessarily find the original class being instantiated by getSingleton

Comment: HI Marius, what would be the fix for this bug? `if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {`

Comment: There shouldn't be a fix I think. you should just make sure that all your objects called via `getSingleton` are objects anyway

Comment: Aha! I also saw LTS is suggesting a pull around this - maybe you are interested. https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/368

Answer (score 0):

If you have maintenance mode ON, make it off . clear cache. and retry to access Magento connect manager. Hope that will work.