# Error: Mage registry key "_singleton/rkt_jscssforsb/observer" already exists

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, registry

I am building a magento B2B webshop
and now I cant do anything with it because of some error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:69:"Mage registry key "_singleton/rkt_jscssforsb/observer" already exists";i:1;s:3637:"#0 app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/rkt_...', false)
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('rkt_jscssforsb/...')
#3 app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('adminhtml_block...', Array)
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(80): Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_block...', Array)
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Diagrams.php(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Diagrams->_prepareLayout()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}";s:3:"url";s:81:"/Magento/index.php/ma_admin/dashboard/index/key/f1e58b7d15977224c929ac0010422f85/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/Magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have done so far and when the errors started to occur? We need more information to help you

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: the error started after i tried to unistall a plugin from the connect manager [js and css for static block](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/js-and-css-for-static-blocks.html) because i didnt need it and i couldnt save static block properly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your PHP developer should be able to solve the exact problem with this trace, but to explain the Problem:

You have an observer which calls `rkt_jscssforsb/observer` as singleton (the default) but this model could not be loaded, so it saves `false` in the registry, which is not recognized by the next call of this singleton as it has the value `false`, so it is tried again to call this singleton, but the registry does not allow to write a value, which already exist.

Thats why you get the error message:
`Mage registry key "_singleton/rkt_jscssforsb/observer" already exists`

As you noted in your comment, you uninstalled a module, if this module had the name `rkt_jscssforsb` you should first try to clean the cache, maybe forcefully by delete `magento/var/cache/*` or try to grep/search trough the code for the occurence of it to clean up the rest

Comment: yeah I have to do it all on my own I know  a litlle PHP But i am all new to magento :$

Comment: Thanks maby that works the i tried to unistall that module but that didnt work

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue while removing the extension manually.

Approach to follow:

1. Revert the changes made.
2. With that, you will get the admin panel. Now, disable compliation at **`system>tools>compilation & disable all the cache types under at system>cache management.`**
3. Now remove the extension the way you were removing.
4. Go to admin panel, it must be working now.
   Clear cache from **`system>cache management.`**

Hope, this help to someone!

Answer (score 2):

Check if your event observer xml code in your module's `config.xml` is all correct.

It should be something like this:

```
<events>
    <event_name_that_you_are_working_on>
        <observers>
            <some_unique_identifier>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>functionNameInYourObserver</method>
            </some_unique_identifier>
        </observers>
    </event_name_that_you_are_working_on>
</events>
```

I once got this kind of error because I was using `modulename/observer` inside class node. Using full class name (`YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer`) solved the error for me.

In your module's event-observer xml code, you might be using `class` like below:

```
<class>yourmodule/observer</class>
```

Try using this instead (as done in above event-observer xml code):

```
<class>YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
```